# Visual studio 2015 freezes when opening Xamarin.android project

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio

I added a new .axml file to my project and VS 2015 freezed and crashed afer a minute or so. This has happened to me before, however, this time, when I try to open the same project, VS 2015 opens but freezes immediately without loading anything from my project. The only way to close it is using task manager.

I tried deleting the .vs hidden folder and packages folder from my solution folder, opening VS with administrator mode, deleting the Visual Studio component model cache without any success. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These actions helped:

- Deleted Bin and Obj folders in my project folder.
- Deleted contents of
  C:\Users{my username}\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips